# How to chain subscriptions on Rx.Observabale? (refactor)

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, rxjs

If I have an `Rx.Observable`, how can I subscribe multiple functions to it via `forEach`? The code below works, but this part in particular feels very un-DRY to me:

```
Rx.Observable.from(definition).forEach(highlight);                   
Rx.Observable.from(definition).forEach(prefix);
```

I know I could create a wrapper function that invokes these two within it, but I like the readability of keeping them separate. What I'd love is to do something akin to

```
Rx.Observable.from(definition).forEach(highlight, prefix)
```

or

```
definition = Rx.Observable.from(definition)
definition.forEach(highlight)
definition.forEach(prefix)
```

or

```
Rx.Observable.from(definition).forEach(highlight).forEach(prefix)
```

... but none of those work. What would be the best way to refactor this?

---

JS:

```
(function commands() {                                                   
  function highlight(node) {                                               
    node.classList.add(hoverClass);                                        
  }                                                                        

  function unhighlight(node) {                                             
    node.classList.remove(hoverClass);                                     
  }                                                                        

  function prefix(node) {                                                  
    node.classList.add(prefixClass);                                       
  }                                                                        

  function unprefix(node) {                                                
    node.classList.remove(prefixClass);                                    
  }                                                                        

  function unprefixAll(nodes) {                                            
    Rx.Observable.from(nodes).forEach(unprefix);                           
  }                                                                        

  var hoverClass  = "hover";                                               
  var prefixClass = "prefixed";                                            
  var $commands  = document.querySelector("#commands");                
  var definitions = Rx.Observable.from($commands.querySelectorAll("dt"))  
    .map(function(_, i) {                                                  
      return $commands.querySelectorAll(                                  
        "dt:nth-of-type("+ (i + 1) +"), dt:nth-of-type("+ (i + 1) +") + dd"
      );                                                                   
    });                                                                    

  definitions.forEach(function (definition) {                              
    Rx.Observable.fromEvent(definition, "mouseover").forEach(function() {  
      definitions.forEach(unprefixAll);                                    
      Rx.Observable.from(definition).forEach(highlight);                   
      Rx.Observable.from(definition).forEach(prefix);                      
    });                                                                    

    Rx.Observable.fromEvent(definition, "mouseout").forEach(function() {   
      Rx.Observable.from(definition).forEach(unhighlight);                 
    });                                                                    
  });                                                                      
})();
```

HTML:

```
<dl id="commands">                                                                          
  <dt class="prefixed">command 1</dt>                                                          
  <dd>does a thing for command 1</dd>   
  <dt>command 2</dt>                                                          
  <dd>does a thing for command 2</dd>    
  <dt>command 3</dt>                                                          
  <dd>does a thing for command 3</dd>    
  <dt>command 4</dt>                                                          
  <dd>does a thing for command 4</dd>                                                                            
  <dt>help</dt>                                                                                
  <dd>Shows all available commands</dd>                                                        
</dl>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should remember that one of the real powers of RxJS is in operator composition.

Rather than trying to `forEach()/subscribe()` through everything (which you can do with traditional javascript arrays without needing to include Rx), you should try to think about how events are transformed and manipulated as they travel down a pipeline.

The following is just one example of how you could do it through a single pipeline:

```
  //Gets a subscription which can be used to clean up all the internal streams
  //Use flatMap to flatten the inner streams into a single stream
  var subscription = definitions.flatMap(function (d) {       
      var mouseOver = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(d, "mouseover");
      var mouseOut = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(d, "mouseout");
      var definition = Rx.Observable.from(d);

      //Merge together both mouseOver and mouseOut so we can cancel them together later
      //Use tap to apply side effects.
      return Rx.Observable.merge(mouseOver.flatMap(definition)
                                          .tap(prefix)
                                          .tap(highlight),
                                 mouseOut.flatMap(definition)
                                         .tap(unprefix)
                                         .tap(unhighlight));

 }).subscribe();
```

**Edit 1**

To elaborate on what is going on here:

1. Use `flatMap` to listen to the `definitions` stream, each value `d` will be an matched element to manipulate.
2. We then create the listeners for the two events as well as one to iterate through the matched elements.
3. Next we use `flatMap` again to capture each event (mouseOver and mouseOut) and project instead the observable for our matched elements.
4. Next we apply side effects through the use of `tap`.
5. `Merge` together both of these streams into a single stream, this is primarily so that the subscriptions get passed back up to the top level.
6. Finally subscribe to the whole chain, then when you dispose of the returned `Disposable` it will clean up all the inner streams as well.

Here is the full working example:

```js
(function commands() {                                                   
  function highlight(node) {                                               
    node.classList.add(hoverClass);                                        
  }                                                                        

  function unhighlight(node) {                                             
    node.classList.remove(hoverClass);                                     
  }                                                                        

  function prefix(node) {                                                  
    node.classList.add(prefixClass);                                       
  }                                                                        

  function unprefix(node) {                                                
    node.classList.remove(prefixClass);                                    
  }                                                                                                                                    
    
  var hoverClass  = "hover";                                               
  var prefixClass = "prefixed";                                            
  var $commands  = document.querySelector("#commands");                
  var definitions = Rx.Observable.from($commands.querySelectorAll("dt"))  
    .map(function(_, i) {                                                  
      return $commands.querySelectorAll(                                  
        "dt:nth-of-type("+ (i + 1) +"), dt:nth-of-type("+ (i + 1) +") + dd"
      );                                                                   
    });
        
  var subscription = definitions.flatMap(function(d) {
      //Declare this stuff up front        
      var mouseOver = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(d, "mouseover");
      var mouseOut = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(d, "mouseout");
      var definition = Rx.Observable.from(d);
            
      return Rx.Observable.merge(mouseOver.flatMap(definition).tap(prefix).tap(highlight),
                                 mouseOut.flatMap(definition).tap(unprefix).tap(unhighlight)).ignoreElements();   
    }).subscribe();
    
    
    
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/2.5.3/rx.all.js"></script>
<dl id="commands">                                                                          
  <dt class="prefixed">command 1</dt>                                                          
  <dd>does a thing for command 1</dd>   
  <dt>command 2</dt>                                                          
  <dd>does a thing for command 2</dd>    
  <dt>command 3</dt>                                                          
  <dd>does a thing for command 3</dd>    
  <dt>command 4</dt>                                                          
  <dd>does a thing for command 4</dd>                                                                            
  <dt>help</dt>                                                                                
  <dd>Shows all available commands</dd>                                                        
</dl>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer--I'm still learning the "reactive way" of thinking about these problems. Would you mind adding a walkthrough explanation of what you're doing here conceptually? Would help me grok the code you wrote a bit better. Thanks!

Comment: @neezer no problem! It can take a while to wrap your head around it. See my update.

Comment: Wonderful, thanks! I think it makes sense... step 3 was the "ah-ha!" moment for me. :)

Comment: One more thing: in your full example, what's the purpose of `.ignoreElements()` at the end?

Comment: Oh right. I threw that on since all the logic is getting handled by the `tap` methods, so it basically just stops non-terminating messages from propagating downstream.  Totally optional.